# "merging" multiple models. To create a "recent activity" box

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

How do you merge models so that I can have the last 10 Posts, Feed Entries and Private Messages displayed in order?

Posts are stored in the "Post" model and ordered on "created_at"

Feed Entries are stored in "Planet" and ordered on "published_at"

Private Messages are stored in "Message" and need to be filtered with:

```
:conditions => "receiver_id = #{current_user.id}"
```

and ordered on "created_at"

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You have to:

1. query elements for each model
2. merge them in a common format
3. sort and limit

Here is some code:

```
class Activity < Struct.new(:title, :text, :date); end

limit = 10
activities = []
activities += Post.all(:order => 'created_at DESC', :limit => limit).map do |post|
  Activity.new(post.title, post.summary, post.created_at)
end

activities += Planet.all(:order => 'published_at DESC', :limit => limit).map do |planet|
  Activity.new(planet.title, planet.message, planet.published_at)
end

activities += Message.all(:conditions => ['receiver_id = ?', current_user.id], :order => 'created_at DESC', :limit => limit).map do |message|
  Activity.new(message.title, message.text, message.created_at)
end

# descending sort by 'date' field
sorted_activities = activities.sort_by(&:date).reverse

# 10 most recent elements across all models
@activities = sorted_activities[0..(limit-1)]
```

Of course, depending on your models, you will have to change which method is used as "title" or "text".

But if you happen to need many of such idioms, you should use Single Table Inheritance as we do in [zena](http://zenadmin.org) (a rails CMS).

Comment: im having a problem with the sorting, it seems to clump all the Posts toegether in order then has the all the Planets together in order instead of mixing them

Comment: Use #sort_by instead: activities.sort_by(&:created_at).reverse[0, limit]

Comment: thanks, it needs to be `@activites=activities.sort_by(&:date).reverse[0, limit]` using :date so that its the field in the Activity class

Answer (score 11):

I would use a Proxy class. The class can store the ActiveRecord object reference and the field for sorting.

```
class ActivityProxy
  attr_accessor :object, :date
  def initialize(object, date)
    self.object = object
    self.date = date
  end
end
```

Then you load your objects.

```
activity = []
activity += Post.all(:limit => 10, :order => "created_at DESC").map { |post| ActivityProxy.new(post, post.created_at) }
# and so on with the other objects
```

Finally you sort the objects

```
activity.sort_by(&:field)
# => here you have the sorted objects
# and you can iterate them with
activity.each do |proxy|
  proxy.object.id
  # ...
end
```

Comment: The activity array appears to be empty, i dont get any errors just an empty array at the end of it

Answer (score 1):

Another method for creating feeds is to create a VIEW that combines the two then let the view have it's own model.

Comment: For an explanation, see: https://dan.chak.org/enterprise-rails/chapter-11-view-backed-models/