# Rails app. Collect items from several models and show this paginated list of items on main page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rails-activerecord

In Rails app I have three models (Posting, Shop::Items and Directory::Items). Every model has relations with other models (User, Category, City ...). All this info I have to show on main page. It should look like paginated list of items. I'm using postgres for DB. 
We can write such code in our controller:

```
@postings = Posting.includes(:category, :subcategory, :user, :city).all
@directory_items = Directory::Item.includes(:category, :user, :city).all
@shop_items = Shop::Item.includes(:category, :user, :city, :phone).all
```

and sort this results. But it is not the best way.

Second solution is to write custom query ommitting ActiveRecord. But this query in really large and it will be hard to support it (we have a lot of joins there) 
What is the best solution for that with the smallest amount of DB queries? (This is main page, so it should work really fast).

Comment: Show us some code. [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)

Comment: I have added some thoughts how it can be implemented. But I don't like those solutions. That is why asking question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are some solutions which are not fast in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2099895/merging-multiple-models-to-create-a-recent-activity-box).

Alternatively you can use [sphinx](http://sphinxsearch.com/) with [thinking sphinx](http://pat.github.com/ts/en/) gem. This way it will be fast and clean.

```
ThinkingSphinx.search classes: [Posting, Shop::Items, Directory::Items], page: params[:page] || 1, per_page: 10
```

Answer (score 0):

As the queries will be cached, only the sorting will take time. If you don't display too many items, developer readability far exceeds the cost to optimize this. You can always do it better if performance is really a bottleneck, but then you still have alternatives to making this code overly complex.